# A lightweight PHP frameworks that provides HTTP router and Access Control

Tags: model-view-controller, php, front-controller

As you know some well-known PHP frameworks have provide front-controller pattern and access control mechanism. Also there are some micro framework that provide front-controller pattern.

I have surveyed some such frameworks and yet could not make a decision, My concerns is:

- Stability
- Stability
- Stability
- Performance
- Security

I do not expect any thing more form my core framework, I will use pure PHP or I may use specific module from various frameworks.

Currently I have experience in ZF 1.x, ZF 2.x, Phalcon frameworks. And I also read Lithium docs, but I found no one suitable for my project.

Also as per [this](http://www.laruence.com/2012/09/16/2791.html), [this](http://www.ruilog.com/blog/view/b6f0e42cf705.html), [this](http://www.comentum.com/web-application-framework-comparison.html) and [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/performance/) pages ZF, Symfony, CakePHP, FuelPHP are not efficient frameworks (fat frameworks).

[image: http://laruence-wordpress.stor.sinaapp.com/uploads/ab-c100-n300002.png]
([image source](http://www.laruence.com/2012/09/16/2791.html))

Can you please suggest a suitable framework or a combination of moudules that satisfy such requirement?

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/115629/752603) related (but old) question.

Comment: These are not requirements, resp. they are requirements every project has and every serious framework can fullfill. Furthermore such questions tend to get you 'I use this and like it' answers which won't help you with your decision.

Comment: See, it already starts. Soon you'll have a list of all the available frameworks here.

Comment: access control is part of the domain logic, which would be for each project different

Comment: stability its a good consideration

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion (because that's all that any answer could be here) the best, lightest weight framework is [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/).  It is very minimal and can integrate with whatever third party libraries you use (including ZF).

Comment: Is there any benchmark to support your opinion?

Comment: Where is Kohana position in the images that is added to question?

Comment: I had great experience with Kohana as well.

Answer (score 1):

I always recommend [the Yii framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/). 
It has great performance - http://www.yiiframework.com/performance/